# how would i 'bridge' 2 seperate faces in

Tags: mesh

[image: picture of what i am trying to bridge]

i cannot for the life of me figure out how to bridge these 2 objects, Ive been looking stuff up for a while and cant find a solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: Join the objects.  Select both "internal" faces.  Use "bridge edge loops" operation.

Comment: maybe bevel the mesh on the right to have the same number of vertices then Ctrl E > Bridge Edge loops?

Comment: bridge edge loop doesnt seem to work, it leaves them visually the same even if i start to fiddle with the settings

Comment: If they're seperate objects you can't bridge them! As @nathan says you'll have to join them with CTRL - J first to make them into one object. Then make sure that the edges have the same number of vertices and use Bridge Edge Loops.